# KmdManager на Windows 10

Tags: c++, kernel, драйвер

Регистрация sys файла драйвера проходит успешно, а вот после попытки запуска пишет что загрузка драйвера была заблокирована. Как решить проблему? Может быть аналоги?

Comment: (1) офтопик, судя по всему. (2) вы думаете, все знают функциональность драйвера по названию? расскажите лучше, какая вам нужна функциональность

Comment: дык какая там функциональность, тестирую хелло ворд кернел драйвер для начала) у меня две системы, в семерке все гуд, но тоже самое в десятке не катит(

Comment: А, это _ваш_ драйвер! Окей, может быть, он не подписан Microsoft? (Скорее всего, так и есть.)

Comment: Какую-то причину блокировки система сообщает? Приведите текст сообщения о блокировке.

Comment: Система ничего не пишет) Пишет KmdManager о том что запуск был отклонен в статусе)

Answer (score 1):

Два варианта:

1. Проверь разрядность системы и драйвера — если отличаются, перекомпилируй под систему.
2. В 10-й нужно отключить проверку цифровой подписи (в случае если ось — х64).